# Ubuntu Server on Power 6 IBM P520

Tags: server, ibm

Can  Ubuntu Server run on an IBM p520 Power6?

Answer (score 3):

IBM support for Ubuntu actually started with IBM Power8 and officially is only support on power8 and future power systems.  The support actually required changes to the fsp.  The older Power system however will support Redhat and SUSE.

See the links below

IBM

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaam/liaamdistros.htm?lang=en 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaam/liaamdistrospower7.htm?lang=en

Ubuntu

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/models/?vendors=IBM

Answer (score 0):

I think there shouldn't be a problem with that depending on what you want to use it for

> "For small scale consolidation servers for UNIX, IBM i and Linux
>   workloads" - IBM Website

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to run the `powerpc` arch, but this is a 32-bits arch, and definitely you will not be able to extract the power of you hardware/system. You will probably not be able to have support from Canonical.